# $ p $ the largest prime factor of $ \vert G \vert $. I show if $ p > 3 $ and $ P \in Syl_{p}(G) $ then $ P \unlhd G $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $ G $ be a soluble group, $ p $ the largest prime factor of $ \vert G \vert $. I show if $ p > 3 $ for prime $ p $ and $ P \in Syl_{p}(G) $ then $ P \unlhd G $.

For proof i employ the induction on $ \vert G \vert $. I should show $ \Phi(G) = 1 $. If $ \Phi(G) \neq 1 $, then $ P\Phi(G)/\Phi(G) $ is normal in $ G/\Phi(G) $, $ P\Phi(G) \unlhd G $. $ P\Phi(G) $ is nilpotent. But i can't tell contradiction.

Comment: The statement is not true, Why would you expect it to be true?

Comment: @DerekHolt I study in a paper

Comment: The smallest counterexample has order $56$.

Comment: Whenever $p\mid 2^n-1$ we can construct a counterexample of order $2^n\cdot p$. Let the subgroup of the roots of unity of order $p$ of the field $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ act on the additive group $A=(\Bbb{F}_{2^n},+)$ and form $G=A\rtimes \mu_p$. The group is non-abelian, so that Sylow $p$-subgroup cannot be normal. You get Derek Holt's counterexample this way with $n=3$, $p=7$. Another small alternative is $n=4$, $p=5$. The group $G$ is clearly solvable.